# Send the request to WebService, I can see response in fiddler, but in my .net code, its null

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0

I am sending a request to the webservice.  I am using fiddler to monitor the result. I did see the response back from the webservice in fiddler. but always get null in my .net code.

```
var svc = new ESB.publishPolicyServices();
publishPolicyResponse response = svc.publishPolicyData(req);
```

response always null.  I am thinking about, probably its not converting the raw response xml to publishPolicyResponse type.  thats why I am not getting it.

is this a bug on hte web service side or my .net code?  let me know if you need more codes to figure out what the problem is.

**Update:**

here's the response xml I get from fiddler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
        <soapenv:Body>
            <message>success</message>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

here's the response type in wsdl.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18060")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.xmlns.abc.com/abc/services/publishPolicyData/envelope/1.0")]
public partial class publishPolicyResponse {

    private string messageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }
}




    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("publishPolicyData", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("publishPolicyResponse", Namespace="http://www.xmlns.abc.com/abc/services/publishPolicyData/envelope/1.0")]
    public publishPolicyResponse publishPolicyData([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.xmlns.abc.com/abc/services/publishPolicyData/envelope/1.0")] publishPolicyRequest publishPolicyRequest) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("publishPolicyData", new object[] {
                    publishPolicyRequest});
        return ((publishPolicyResponse)(results[0]));
    }
```

Comment: `let me know if you need more codes to figure out what the problem is.` We do. The small piece you provided should work, if everything else is alright. I am thinking that maybe you have to update the WS's proxy definitions in the client application?

Comment: sorry, not sure what else I should include.

Comment: Doesn't look like it from the code, but are you sure something isn't being done async?

Comment: Whats happens if you download and install soapui? Test the webservice through that and you can tell for sure if the problem is your client code or the web service?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the webservice so you could debug it if required? Is your code posted above inside a try/catch statement? Does if fail on the webservice call if its not in try/catch block.  Trying to make sure your not swallowing an exception

Comment: @Kyle in soupui, it works.  put it in try/catch, no error catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to consume a third-party service, not under your control and probably not written using WCF.

As it looks like from the XML you show, the body is not wrapped. WCF expects this by default, so this message should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
    <soapenv:Body>
        <r:publishPolicyResponse xmlns:r="http://www.xmlns.abc.com/abc/services/publishPolicyData/publishPolicyResponse">
            <message>success</message>
        </r:publishPolicyResponse>      
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can instruct WCF to not expect a wrapped message body by addingthe following attribute to the `publishPolicyResponse` class, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280830/wcf-how-to-enforce-messagecontractattribute-iswrapped-false-generation):

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
```

You most likely would want to do this in a separate file, like `publishPolicyResponsePartial.cs`.

Comment: not sure where to put it, but I put it right above "public partial class publishPolicyResponse {", still not working.

Comment: @feelexit did you figure it out?